# Opening Google Directions API internally Android Studio

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I am currently developing an application in Android Studio and I have included both the Google Maps API and Google Directions API within the app. I have included a button in my app which allows the user to be guided to their selected location.

The following code uses the Google Maps API, opens up Google Maps within the application but shows the marker on the maps without giving directions to that place:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker at the Oval and move the camera
    LatLng oval = new LatLng(53.3484013,-6.2605243);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(oval).title("Oval Pub"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(oval));
```

The below code uses the Google Directions API and gives the user a guide to their selected destination:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=The+Oval+Bar,+Dublin+Ireland");
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(mapIntent);
```

The only problem being the above code relating to the Google Directions API, opens the Google Maps application outside my application. I was wondering how to get it to open within the application itself.

Comment: You'll need to parse the data you're receiving from Directions Api and draw paths from it onto MapView.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment as shown in this great Lars Vogel article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: The Google Maps runs withing my app, the problem is that I need the Google Directions to run inside my app. When I click the button it brings up directions to my selected location but it does it externally on the Google Maps application itself.